# Insect Identification - Ecuador

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I took a picture of this bug while I was in Chucchilán Ecuador in June. I am wondering what type of insect this is?

It was about 1-inch long.

This was the only good photo I was able to take, sorry for the poor angle.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a phasmid (Order [Phasmatodea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasmatodea)) from the Genus [Monticomorpha](http://phasmida.speciesfile.org/Common/basic/Taxa.aspx?TaxonNameID=1199515). Its common name in Spanish is *(insecto) ututo*.

Here is an image of it:

[image]

<sup>Source: http://www.projectnoah.org/spottings/1847685515</sup>

They are found in Colombia, Ecuador and Peru. You can see that the distribution matches your place:

[image]

<sup>Source: http://phasmida.speciesfile.org/Common/editTaxon/Distribution/ShowDistribution.aspx?TaxonNameID=1199515</sup>

Identifying the species may be a bit more complicated. The *[Phasmida Species File](http://phasmida.speciesfile.org/Common/basic/Taxa.aspx?TaxonNameID=1199515)* page I linked above lists 8 species of ututos (with pictures), 5 of them occurring in Ecuador.